# Resteasy spring security - duplicate requests

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, servlets, spring-security, resteasy

I'm having hard time to get RESTeasy working with my existing application. I can hit my end points (AdminService). My problem is everytime I make a GET request (over browser) I hit twice on my service so it leads to duplicate results. I tried with POST using a java client still the problem is there. Following you can find my technology list.

Spring security 3.x
Spring 2.5
RestEasy 2.3.5.Final

==Part of my web.xml==

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>au.com.esriau.dekho.application.ApplicationLoader</listener-class>
</listener>


<listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
    </listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
    </servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
    <param-value>rest</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.resources</param-name>
    <param-value>com.admin.AdminService
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

I'd appreciate your solution or idea to trouble shoot this.

cheers

Comment: Guys - just found it's common to all servlets in my configuration..not just RESTeasy servlet... Let me know if you can think of any reason pls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't bother reading this. This was due to my custom implementation of AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter in spring-security. I was basically making unnecessary call to the super class with super.doFilter(request, response, chain). This was done right after I execute my custom filters. Getting rid of super.doFilter resolved the issue for me.